# kafka producer gets stuck

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring kafka, we see our producers getting stuck when invoking get on listenable future

my code

```
try {
  kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(event).get();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

we use max.block.ms default of 60000 (60 Seconds) but I never get an interruption or execution exception it seemed like is waiting on the get forever

is the kafka template attempting over and over to send the message or it should fail?

Comment: What version are you using? Very old kafka-clients used to block like this if the broker was down. The template simply delegates the send to the kafka `Producer`. Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.apache.kafka` to see what's happening.

Comment: org.apachekafka:kafka-clients:2.0.1

Comment: That one shouldn't hang (for longer than max.block.ms); debug logging is the next step; also take a thread dump to see what the thread is doing. The template does not retry, it completes the future when the send callback is invoked by the kafka clients.

Comment: Is your broker configured to auto create topics/does the topic exist in kafka already? I've seen instances where if the broker isn't configured to auto create the topic and the producer tries to produce to the topic that doesn't exist, the request hangs because the producer is waiting for the topic to be created to write to it.